# How to get data through pandas with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, binance-api-client

How can i get the symbols of retdf

```
import pandas as pd
returns = [0.0322, 0.3211, 0.0032, 0.00349]
symbols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

retdf = pd.DataFrame(returns, index=symbols, columns=['ret'])
retdf = retdf.ret.nlargest(3).values > 0.03
print(retdf)
```

The above code outputs

```
array([ True,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use boolean indexing after your condition is met.

```
tmp = retdf.ret.nlargest(3)
(tmp.loc[tmp > 0.03]).index
> Index(['B', 'A'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> retdf[retdf['ret'] > 0.03].nlargest(3, 'ret')
      ret
B  0.3211
A  0.0322

# OR

>>> retdf.nlargest(3, 'ret').query('ret > 0.03')
      ret
B  0.3211
A  0.0322
```